# JavaScript's addition result in weird result

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I have encountered strange phenomeon while calculating some checksum. So I reduced this problem into small script.

```
% node
Welcome to Node.js v16.1.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> console.log( ( 0x20000026c6db24 + 0x8bf8a215 ).toString( 16 ) )
200000b2bf7d38
```

In Safari and Chrome.

```
<script>
console.log( ( 0x20000026c6db24 + 0x08bf8a215 ).toString( 16 ) )
</script>

Browser's console
200000b2bf7d38
```

I think it must be 200000b2bf7d39. Please let me know why this calculation result in 200000b2bf7d38.

Comment: is either number, or the result, bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`? - tehre's always `console.log( ( 0x20000026c6db24n + 0x08bf8a215n ).toString( 16 ) )`

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, 0x20000026c6db24 is bigger than 0x1fffffffffffff, it must be the reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you use the wrong type. JS Number can not be treated as a fixed nor floating-point. But such a big numbers `0x20000026c6db24 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` can not be used safely in the context of fixed-point calculations.
But `BigInt` could be used explicitly:

```
(BigInt('0x20000026c6db24') + BigInt('0x8bf8a215')).toString(16) // '200000b2bf7d39'
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt